# Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo cannot be started

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have a problem starting emulator in visual studio enteerprise 2017, version 15.9.10. please help me

the output of running is :

```
Starting runtime checks
Starting emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo ...
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsumeWS.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: VT feature disabled in BIOS/UEFI
Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo cannot be started.
Runtime checks completed
Build has been canceled.
```

and the log is :

> 2019-03-28T10:43:25.1791248+04:30~07: Updating device availability
>   2019-03-28T10:45:25.1918554+04:30~23: Updating device availability

Comment: Did you do what the error message tells you? Did you ensure Windows Hypervisor is installed? Did you check virtualization status in BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: is your CPU AMD or Intel?

Comment: Has you checked hyper-v ?

Comment: you could refer the document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Answer (score 0):

> Did you checked Hyper-V is enabled or installed ?

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

> - Do not remember that Hyper-V role cannot be installed on Windows 10
>     Home Edition.